# "No parse:read" error when running app

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and this is only my second app, so forgive me if the answer to my question is obvious.

I'm trying to implement Thompson's RegExp code to implement an NFA for regular expressions. My app has 2 inputs so far: 1) First line - the number of expressions to implement (converted to Int), and 2) Second line - the regular expression to implement. Later on I'll be have a 3rd input on the same line as the regular expression to implement. This means that I'll need to learn how to parse the second input string to get a string and an integer. But I couldn't find how to parse the IO String yet. I guess that's another question for later, or maybe someone can provide a link on how to do it. Input will look like this:

```
(int input)
regex1 (int input) 
regex2 (int input) 
regex3 (int input)
```

Here's the pertinent code...there's a lot more, but only showing the relevant. The error I'm getting now is a "no parse:read" when I just enter anything for the second input (second line). The second input isn't used for now since I've temporarily hard coded for the second input. I'm in Leksah and the code configures and compiles. Could someone tell me why I'm getting the parse error when I run the app?

```
data Reg = Epsilon |
           Literal Char |
           Or Reg Reg |
           Then Reg Reg |
           Star Reg
           deriving Eq


-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--                                  --
--  ImplementNfa.hs     
--
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

trans :: Ord a => Nfa a -> String -> Set a

trans mach str = foldl step startset str
         where
         step set ch = onetrans mach ch set
         startset = closure mach (sing (startstate mach))

-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--  Turn the result of trans into printable form.           --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

print_trans :: Nfa Int -> String -> [Char]

print_trans mach str = show (flatten (trans mach str))


buildRE::String -> Reg
buildRE r = regexp2  -- will build regex from "re" 
                     -- hard coded for now until I
                     -- learn how to parse a string

re = "(ab|ba)" -- Hard coded for now until I can
               -- learn how to parse an input string

a = Literal 'a'
b = Literal 'b'

regexp2 = Or (Then a b) (Then b a)

main::IO()
main = do input1 <- getLine
          let t = (read input1::Int)
          let t1 = t -1
          -- Maybe I need a loop here for "t" but I don't know how
          if (t1 == -1)
              then return()
              else
                   do input <- getLine
                      -- Need to figure out how to parse input
                      -- to get string 're' and an Int
                      let r = buildRE re
                      let nfa1 = build r
                      putStrLn $ (print_trans nfa1 re);
```

Comment: From the code you've posted, the only place that `read` is called is for the *first* line of input -- unless `build` calls `read` somewhere? (You don't seem to indicate where `build` comes from.)

Comment: The second getLine isn't supposed to be used for now. "r" for "build r" is supposed to be hard coded for now. Maybe I've not declared "r" correctly or it has to be "read" somehow. "build" is defined earlier on and I thought it was too much to post. "Build" takes a "Reg" input and outputs an "Nfa Int".

Comment: There is nothing in what you posted that would give a parse error with the kind of input you're describing. The error must be elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: I got it. I was entering the first input on the same line as the .exe. You have to: exe, enter, 1st input, enter, 2nd input, enter. Silly I know. But I'm coming from Visual Studio.